# Problem with updating ForEach with changing number of items - .count seems to return wrong value

Tags: swift, foreach, swiftui

I created a simple view designed to show the content of an array that is stored in an Observable Object property:

```
struct Satellite {
    let name: String
    let orbit: Double
    let color: Color
}

class OrbitalSystem: ObservableObject{
    @Published var objects: [Satellite] =  []
}


struct OrbitalSystemView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var orbitalSystem: OrbitalSystem
    
    var body: some View{

        VStack{
            ForEach(0..<orbitalSystem.objects.count){ n in
                HStack{
                    Text("\(orbitalSystem.objects[n].name)")
                    Spacer()
                    Text("\(orbitalSystem.objects[n].orbit, specifier: "%.2f")")
                }
                .padding()
                .background(orbitalSystem.objects[n].color)
            }.padding()
        }
    }
}
```

Then I want to use this general view in ContentView, however in the App I'm using a different struct for the data (struct Planet) than the one used in the general view (struct Satellite).  In order to keep the required changes minimal I added a computed property to the struct Planet converting the content of Planet to an element Satellite. With any change to my array of Planets in ContentView a property observer converts it to an array of Satellites and stores it in the ObservedObject property. To update the view when initially loaded the Array of Planets is set by using the .onAppear modifier.

```
struct Planet {
    let name: String
    let distanceToSun: Int
    let surface: Color
    
    var satellite : Satellite {
        Satellite(name: self.name, orbit: Double(self.distanceToSun), color: self.surface)
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var planetarySystem = OrbitalSystem()
    
    @State private var planets: [Planet] = []{
        didSet{
            var objects = [Satellite]()
            for planet in planets {
                objects.append(planet.satellite)
            }
            planetarySystem.objects = objects
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
            OrbitalSystemView(orbitalSystem: planetarySystem)
                .onAppear{
                    planets = [
                        Planet(name: "Mercury", distanceToSun: 1, surface: Color.orange),
                        Planet(name: "Venus", distanceToSun: 2, surface: Color.gray),
                        Planet(name: "Earth", distanceToSun: 3, surface: Color.blue),
                        Planet(name: "Mars", distanceToSun: 4, surface: Color.red)
                    ]
                }
    }
}
```

This code works in principle but has a very strange behavior. My expected result would be: [A Stack of four lines listing: Mercury 1.00, Venus 2.00, Earth 3.00, Mars 4.00 with different colors in the background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O56mf.png)

however with the code above I get an empty view. I get the expected result by modifying the the OrbitalSystem Class like this:

```
class OrbitalSystem: ObservableObject{
    @Published var objects: [Satellite] =  [
        Satellite(name: "", orbit: 0, color: Color.white),
        Satellite(name: "", orbit: 0, color: Color.white),
        Satellite(name: "", orbit: 0, color: Color.white),
        Satellite(name: "", orbit: 0, color: Color.white)
    ]
}
```

if

```
@Published var objects: [Satellite] =  [
            Satellite(name: "", orbit: 0, color: Color.white),
            Satellite(name: "", orbit: 0, color: Color.white)
            ]
```

is changed to this the resulting view also shows only two rows: [Mercury 1.00 and Venus 2.00 with the respective background colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1b4dK.png).

It therefore seems the .count in the ForEach(0..<orbitalSystem.objects.count) returns the wrong value even though the content of the array has been updated.

I'm using Xcode 12.3

I'd be grateful for any clarification on this behavior. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data is dynamic (will change while the view is on screen) you need to give each item an ID so that the view knows when to update.

**METHOD 1: You can give it a local ID by just changing your ForEach loop:**

```
        VStack{
            ForEach(orbitalSystem.objects.indices, id: \.self) { n in
                HStack{
                    Text("\(orbitalSystem.objects[n].name)")
                    Spacer()
                    Text("\(orbitalSystem.objects[n].orbit, specifier: "%.2f")")
                }
                .padding()
                .background(orbitalSystem.objects[n].color)
            }.padding()
        }
```

**METHOD 2: You can make Satellite conform to Identifiable and give each item it's own ID when you init() the item. Here you could customize the ID if needed and the ForEach doesn't need to loop on the index, but rather the object itself.**

1. Make Satellite conform to Identifiable.

   ```
   struct Satellite: Identifiable {
       let id = UUID()
       let name: String
       let orbit: Double
       let color: Color
   }
   ```
2. Update for each to loop

   ```
            VStack{
                ForEach(orbitalSystem.objects) { object in
                    HStack{
                        Text("\(object.name)")
                        Spacer()
                        Text("\(object.orbit, specifier: "%.2f")")
                    }
                    .padding()
                    .background(object.color)
                }.padding()
            }
   ```

If you take a look at the different init methods of the ForEach, you'll notice that the `Range<Int>` method computes views "on demand over a given **constant range**." So, you need to use one of the other inits for dynamic data.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, the suggestions work. However I do still not understand why it is required to include the id. The new Array is sent to an @Published Property of an Observed Object. This should entail an update of the UI and it actually does, but the .count value is not updated with the array, and this is what I do not understand. Do you have any explanation for that?

Comment: I edited my answer with more details from the Developer Documentation. Please mark as correct answer if you agree.

Comment: "constant range" is obviously the key to my problem. Good to know. Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem. Happy to help!